# I'm creating discord bot that plays audio but i got this eror "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating discord bot that plays audio but i got this eror "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found"

here my code
music.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Et ole puhelussa vitun apina!")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FNPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_optopms': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FNPEG_OPTIONS)

            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("MUSIIKKI PYSÄYTETTY")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("MUSIIKKI JATKUU")



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

run.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?",
intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)

client.run("MTA0ODUzNjcyMjY3NTMzNTE3OA.G4CK62.BwAK0qKYvuOYU_tm7-cVNCctL4RnnSDtIHmfyc")
```

i tried commads but they are not working it only says "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "commad i was trying" is not found"

Answer (score 0):

As of discord.py 2, the [add_cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_cog) method has become an `async function`, so you need to `await` it. And if you're using a cog from a other file, it is suggested to use [load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) to load it. For example:

**cogs/music.py**

```py
class Music(commands.Cog):
    ...

# as of discord.py 2, this function needs to be an async function
async def setup(bot): 
    await bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

**main.py**

```py
# subclass the bot to override the "setup_hook" method
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    async def setup_hook(self):
        cogs_to_load = ("cogs.music",) # tuple of paths to the cogs you wanted to load

        # use "load_extension" to load all the cogs
        for cog in cogs_to_load:
            await self.load_extension(cog)

bot = MyBot()

...
```

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/extensions.html) is an example of extensions, and [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs) is an example of cogs.